# How can I share data from one component in JSS with Vue Js?

Tags: jss

*As a* developer,
*I want* to change data from a component in ONE place,
*so that* I don't need to duplicate this data for each pages

How can I ask to my
*src/app/components/**header-nav.vue***

```
<template>
    <sc-link :field="fields.link" />         
</template>

<script>
import { Link } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue';

  export default {
    name: 'HeaderNav',
    props: {
      fields: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({}),
      }
    },
    data:  function () {
      return {}
    },
    components: {
      ScLink: Link,
    }
  };
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

to use data from
***data/components/header-nav/en.json***

```
{
  "name": "Header Nav",
  "componentName": "HeaderNav",
  "fields": {
    "link": { 
      "value": {
        "href": "/services",
        "title": "Services",
        "text": "Services"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

instead of
***data/routes/en.json***

```
{
  "name": "services",
  "displayName": "Services",
  "placeholders": {
    "main": [
      {
        "componentName": "HeaderNav",
        "fields": {
          "link": {
            "value": {
              "href": "/services",
              "title": "Services",
              "text": "Services"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using *ID references* introduced in technical preview 3.

Essentially, you define a shared piece of component content under `/data/component-content`, give it an explicit, app-wide-unique `id` value, and then refer to it from a route to include the shared reference.

The Angular Basic app has an example of doing this [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/cda6450b024d8fa801f88d0dac31ab335ab9ec06/samples/basic-sample-angular/data/routes/en.yaml#L31). It is using YAML instead of JSON for its route data, but the equivalent JSON structure also works.

Note that ID references work at a component level, but not a route level. So while you can share a single piece of lorem ipsum component content throughout the app if you wish, you cannot literally re-route the same route to a different shared *route*. If you wanted to do some route rewriting behavior, you'd need to implement your custom logic in `/sitecore/definitions/routes.sitecore.js`, which is where all the YAML/JSON files are parsed into the manifest.

Note: for Vue in TP3, you'll also need to borrow the missing `/sitecore/definitions/component-content.sitecore.js` file from [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/8b0ee5ce594b79b74eba89a4f3b8a5396ccb89a3/samples/advanced-sample-react/sitecore/definitions/component-content.sitecore.js) to get `component-content` to build into the manifest. This will not be necessary for versions after technical preview 3.

Comment: Hi @kam-Figy, 1- I renamed my folder to /data/ **component-content** /Header-nav/ 2- I added an ID: "id": "ID__header-nav", 3 - I made a reference to that ID (same as The Angular Basic app) 4 - I have this error: _The item ID ID__header-nav was referred to, but it was not defined!_ I think we need one more step. Thanks

Comment: Are your component-content items being added to the manifest? (i.e. does `/sitecore/definitions/component-content.sitecore.js` exist)

Comment: I find the last step : Add a new file : sitecore\definitions\component-content.sitecore.js same as https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/8b0ee5ce594b79b74eba89a4f3b8a5396ccb89a3/samples/advanced-sample-react/sitecore/definitions/component-content.sitecore.js

Comment: That'll be present for Vue in the next release, found that issue yesterday :)

Comment: Thanks Kam, this file was missing, can you edit your answer to add this last step ? And I will Approve it !